# Opinion: Is there a better way to save data to core data from parsed CSV file

Tags: csv, core-data, swift3

I am parsing a csv file into core data. I am parsing the file and saving the data into CD at the same time in the one function. I am interested to get some feedback if this is a good approach? It does work, the data is saved. To make things easy for now all the entity attributes are strings. I am new to swift so am looking to make sure I am not making any newbie mistakes. Here is the function.
I do have one question. I am not sure now to save data from the file to an attribute in a different entity in the same data model that has a relationship to the Asteroids entity. A resources and amount attributes in a Resources entity for example.

```
func parseAsteroidCSVForCD(){

    let context = getContext()
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Asteroid", in: context)
    let manageObj = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: context)


    // Path variable to the asteroids.csv file
    let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "asteroids", ofType: "csv")!

    // Parse the file in a do catch
    do {
        // Use the paser to pull out the rows
        let csv = try CSV(contentsOfURL: path)
        let rows = csv.rows

        // Go through each row to store the id, name, size, distance and value
        for row in rows {
            let id = row["id"]!
            let name = row["name"]!
            let size = row["size"]!
            let distance = row["distancefromEarth"]!
            let value = row["value"]!

            // load into Core Data here
            manageObj.setValue(id, forKey: "id")
            manageObj.setValue(name, forKey: "name")
            manageObj.setValue(size, forKey: "size")
            manageObj.setValue(value, forKey: "value")
            manageObj.setValue(distance, forKey: "distance")

            do {
                try context.save()
                print("New Asteroid has been created")

            } catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }

        }

    } catch let err as NSError {

        print(err.debugDescription)
    }
}
```

Comment: You should be using instances of the `Asteroid` subclass, not `NSManagedObject`.

Answer (score 0):

With this logic, all CSV rows will not be inserted. Because you create only one "manageObj" and keep on setting the value of every row to it. So finally you will have only one "manageObj" with the last row value.

the entity creation should be within the for loop, so that for every row, a new entity will be created. And do not save within the for loop. Once for loop is finished, save it.. A single save..

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I understand the logic better now

Comment: I have been working on this for a few hours now and I would like to know is it possible to save to CD from an array of objects for example in this case several instances of the Asteroid class?

Comment: What you mean by CD? Compact Disk? Or you meant DB, DataBase? Could you give more details about your requirement?

Comment: I mean Core Data. I want to know if it is possible to parse the csv file into a n array of object Asteroid. The Asteroid class is in a separate swift file. I append the array.

Comment: Ignore previous comment. I mean Core Data. I want to know if it is possible to parse the csv file into a n array of object Asteroid and then go through the array and save into core data?

Comment: I have rewritten the function and it appears to be working with a bit tweaking. I did not save into an array first making the function easier to code.